# Divide 2n array in n group in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I ran into trouble writing a program for class:

Given an array of even length, and a pairwise validity test, I must partition the array elements into pairs that each pass the validity test.  So I might compare `array[0]` and `array[1]` at first, and if not valid, then compare `array[0]` and `array[2]`, etc.

For example, if the input array has length is 6 and elements `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, then a valid overall result might be `{{0,2}, {1,3}, {4,5}}`, in which every element of the original array appears exactly once, and every pair is valid according to the validity test method.

I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is.  You seem to say that you have a method by which you want to test pairs' validity, so what problem do you have with passing pairs of elements to that method?

Comment: My problem is how to generate n pairs which are all valid, like we have{(0,2), (1,3), (4,5)}, 0 and 2 are valid when putting together, and same as the rest of these.

Comment: Once you find a valid pair, is it certain that the rest of the elements can be paired up successfully?  Or is it possible, for example, that after finding (0, 2) to be a valid pair you might later have to backtrack and try a different partner for 0?

Comment: No it's not certain. But eventually I will find n groups which could be paired up successfully.

Comment: Is the validity test commutative?  Do you have to worry about argument order?  In other words, do you have to consider `{0, 2}` a different pair from `{2, 0}`?

Comment: The order doesn't matter, and if there's an odd array, I think there should be one element that is in only one group.

Comment: Do please check the edit.  The original language was very difficult to follow, but I think I've captured it.

Comment: Sorry about that! Yes the edit is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: You can have something like this.

An auxiliar method to remove elements in position `a` and `b` from `origin`.

```
private static int[] remove(int[] origin, int a, int b) {
    int[] result = new int[origin.length - 2];
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < origin.length; j++) {
        if (j != a && j != b) {
            result[i] = origin[j];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And your final method. You can create your own Exception. This exception is thrown when the first element of the array has not encountered a valid pair. It is a way to implement **backtracking**. In the call to `yourProblem(remove(array, 0, i))`, this exception can be thrown. Therefore, `validPar` is added to the arrayList after getting a result of the call (this means, a solution has been encountered and no exceptions have been thrown). Note the **recursivity** implemented.

```
public static ArrayList<int[]> yourProblem (int[] array) {
    ArrayList<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return result;
    } else if (array.length == 1) {
        int[] validPar = {array[0]};    // If odd elements
        result.add(validPar);
        return result;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        try {
            if (valid(array[0], array[i])) {
                ArrayList<int[]> next = yourProblem(remove(array, 0, i));
                int[] validPar = {array[0], array[i]};
                result.add(validPar);
                result.addAll(next);
                return result;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: I made a method that returns the desired pairs that are valid. (1,3) and (1,5) can be valid both. But question is not really specific.

Comment: Yes, I've tested it, and this might use array several times.

Comment: Is it what you searched?

Comment: I want something generated like {(0,2), (1,3), (4,5)}, and every element just appears once. 0 and 2 are valid when putting together, and same as the rest of these.

Comment: All elements are always going to be valid? I mean, if you have (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 4) as valid pairs, you can have an ouput {(1, 2)} or another {(1,3), (2,4)}. Which one do you want, complete or ordered?

Comment: I will find something like (0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5) which means all the elements would be paired up at last.

Comment: What about if you have odd elements?

Comment: Then this one will be one group only

Comment: I edited answer with a solution.

Comment: Thank you very  much!

Comment: Nice! Dont forget to mark as answered if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

I will not write your homework for you, but I will try to get you going in a hopefully useful direction.

One approach you could take would be to examine all the possible orderings of the whole input array until you find one in which each consecutive pair of elements is valid.  There are `n!` orderings of an array of length `n`, so this scales very poorly.  It also tests many pairs multiple times each, and generally makes no use of validity tests it has already performed to narrow the possible solution space.  But if you already know how to enumerate the permutations then it has the advantage of not requiring much more than that.

---

Another general avenue would be to build the solution one pair at a time, which seems to be the general approach you described in your question.  Such an approach would be a great deal easier if you didn't need to worry about backtracking, but the backtracking requirement isn't a killer.

You can scan through pairs of elements using nested loops, generally as described in another answer.  The first trick, then, is to use each element exactly once.  One way to do that would involve swapping array elements to form pairs as you go, so that after finding each pair the remaining unpaired elements are all at the tail end of the array.  This makes backtracking a bit tricky, but not impossible -- the second trick is to reverse the swaps when needed.  This lends itself fairly well to a recursive implementation, maybe having this form:

```
/**
 * Attempts to rearrange the elements of a tail of array, starting at index
 * start, so that each consecutive element pair satisfies the validity criterion.
 * If unsuccessful, restores the array elements to their initial order before
 * returning.
 * 
 * @param array the array whose elements are to be paired
 * @param start the index of the first element of the tail
 * @return true if and only if the elements of the tail were successfully paired
 */
boolean formPairs(int array[], int start) {
    // ...
}
```

The entry point to the recursion would ordinarily be by passing `0` as the start index.  The recursion would terminate whenever `start + 1` was greater than or equal to the array length (success!), or when no pair could be formed with element `array[start]` (failure).

---

There are other variations as well, but it seems unlikely that anything more complicated than the above would be expected of you at your apparent level.